# Change view based on login in Shinyapps io

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app where the user view changes based on who has logged in. I have seen examples of this being done using Shiny server pro or R Studio connect but since we don't have much budget for that software we are still doing it using shinyapps io. Has any tried doing it there or have some examples which I can refer to . Thank you.

Comment: Do you want every user to have a personalized view, or do you have some kind of user groups?

Comment: groups would be more convenient but is that doable with shinyapps

Comment: I added an answer below. Did you find it useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the user to log in in the shiny app, and use `conditionalPanel` logic to render different UIs for different groups.

The minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.group == 0",
    textInput("groupname", "Enter your group name to proceed")
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.group == 1",
    uiOutput("group1UI")
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.group == 2",
    uiOutput("group2UI")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Logic for deciding the group
  output$group <- reactive({
    if (input$groupname == "group1") {
      return(1)
    } else if (input$groupname == "group2") {
      return(2)
    } else {
      return(0)
    }
  })
  outputOptions(output, "group", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

  # View for group 1
  output$group1UI <- renderUI({
    mainPanel(
      h3("Group 1 view"),
    )
  })

  # View for group 2
  output$group2UI <- renderUI({
    mainPanel(
      h3("Group 2 view"),
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Notice that this is not a secure way to identify the users / protect their data, just a way to build the functionality you desired. Security must be implemented separately, but it's beyond the scope here.